# ListView footer not expanding to parent width

Tags: android, listview

In my ListView I have a footerview but its TextView is not expanding to the width of the parent. Here is my footer xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvShowMore"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Show more"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And here is my code:

```
          LayoutParams llParams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
          viewFooterShowMore.setLayoutParams(llParams);
          lvEvents.addFooterView(viewFooterShowMore);
```

Comment: Looks like that all be will fine. Mistake is simple i think. recheck your layout file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using

```
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
```

Comment: Sorry, match parent, try that

Comment: match_parent works. Why would fill_parent not? Don't see the logic.

Comment: It's just an annoying thing that you've got to play with sometimes! You'll get used to it! If the answer helped, please accept it by clicking the big tick :)

Comment: fill_parent doesn't work b/c listview will fill the all remaining space on parent AFAIK. If there is already a button in parent which is left to listview and you use fillparent listview width goes to right end but not left. But with match_parent it does. I might be wrong though, I always encounter error while doing UI.